# SSH.Net creating user account

Tags: user-accounts, ssh.net

I'm trying to use SSH.NET to activate user accounts on my Linux Ubuntu VPS server.

I'm using the following code:

```
public void CreateUser()
{
    var connectionInfo = new Renci.SshNet.PasswordConnectionInfo("serverip", "root", "serverpassword");   
    using (var ssh = new Renci.SshNet.SshClient(connectionInfo))
    {
        string username = tbUser.Text;
        string password = tbPass.Text;
        ssh.Connect();
        var command = ssh.RunCommand("useradd " + username + " -s /bin/false");
        command.Execute();
        command = ssh.RunCommand("passwd " + password);
        command.Execute();
        command = ssh.RunCommand(password);
        command.Execute();
        command = ssh.RunCommand(password);
        command.Execute();
        ssh.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

When manually creating a user, I would run `useradd username -s /bin/false` (to give the user no ssh access). Then I would run `passwd username`.

This is where my error comes in. The application just freezes when running the `passwd  + password` command. I think it's because Linux asks you to enter the password and ssh.net thinks that it's waiting for a response. When I just run the first (`useradd`) command, then the user is added and the program doesn't freeze. It just freezes with the second `RunCommand`.

Is there any way to create user accounts in the way I'm trying to do this using SSH.Net?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the double quotes to single quotes worked for me:

```
ssh.Connect();

var command = ssh.CreateCommand("useradd " + username + " -s /bin/false");
command.Execute();

command = ssh.CreateCommand("echo '" + username + ":" + password + "' >> create.txt");
command.Execute();
command = ssh.CreateCommand("chpasswd < create.txt");
command.Execute();
command = ssh.CreateCommand("rm create.txt");
command.Execute();

ssh.Disconnect();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have issue, you try change passwd for current user

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).